# Debian (buster) requiring iwlwifi-5000[1-5].ucode

Tags: installation, debian, wifi, debian-buster

During Debian (buster) installation, I got a message telling me that the files 
*iwlwifi-5000[1-5].ucode* were needed. I first finished installing without the files.

Then, after reading this related page:

https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/firmware-iwlwifi/download

I have added the following line to the file */etc/apt/sources.list*

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main non-free
```

but when running the command:

```
aptitude search iwlwifi
```

I don't get any result.

Did I forget something or did anything the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid mistake for those often using aptitude or apt.
I had forgotten to run:

```
aptitude update
```

after modifying the file */etc/apt/sources.list*

Hoping this will be useful to someone.